# I'm looking for Ubuntu drivers for the Broadcom BRCM 1058 Wireless adaptor

Tags: drivers, broadcom

I was wondering if anyone could help me get a hold of broadcom BRCM 1058 drivers for Ubuntu 14.

Thanks for your time and support,
Heiko

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4` please ?

Comment: Network controller [0280] Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:05e2]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install them by running in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) :

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If those two packages are already installed, try to run :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```